# why the while loop does not end?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have the following scenario,

```py
def gen(n):
    while n:
       if n > 10:
           n = 0
       n+=1
       yield n
```

from my intuition, when ever `n` is set to zero, the loop should stop. Yet, ops in the loop repeat in a cycle. Such that `n to 10; n set to 0; 0 to 10`.

I really don't understand this.

Comment: When is `n==0` exactly? You increment it by `1` just after you set it to `0`

Comment: `n` needs to be `0` at the time the `while` condition is being checked; it reaching `0` somewhere inside the loop doesn't count.

Comment: yeah, little tricky at times but definitely that was the problem. Funny how it was all set up.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

```
def gen(n):
    while n:
       if n > 10:
           n = 0
           break
       n+=1 
       yield n
```

Solution 2:

```
def gen(n):
    while n:
       n+=1
       if n > 10:
           n = 0
       yield n
```

You simply are not exiting when n becomes 0, so it is becoming 1 again.